# mysql database connections will be migrated

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am not DBA, just use MySQL on local machine for testing my apllications.

I have MySQL server with Workbench and Notifier on Windows machine. MySQL Notifier periodically shows message "mysql database connections will be migrated" with possibility to click "No".
What does this message means? Why it wants to migrate connections?

Comment: I have the same question.  There is also an outstanding unanswered question on this same topic at the MySQL forum here: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,657636,657636

Comment: perhaps:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html

Comment: The documentation is a bit dense on the subject of migration. Does anyone have the "For Dummies" answer?

Answer (score 1):

This [answer was given at the MySQL forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?173,657636,659388#msg-659388) by Javier Treviño from the  MySQL on Windows Team:

> Some products are able to share connection information to MySQL Server
>   instances with MySQL Workbench. The products that do this are MySQL
>   for Excel, MySQL Notifier and MySQL for Visual Studio.
>
> By sharing connection information this means that if MySQL Workbench
>   is installed in the same computer, all of these programs will attempt
>   to use the same configuration file where MySQL Workbench stores the
>   information about connections.
>
> So, if any of the 3 aforementioned products are installed but MySQL
>   Workbench is not, they will fallback to use their own separate
>   configuration file to store connection information, but as soon as
>   they detect MySQL Workbench is present, they will attempt to migrate
>   or move the connections stored in the separate configuration file to
>   the file MySQL Workbench uses.
>
> The product presents a dialog with the message you have been talking
>   about in this forum thread. You should notice there is a More Info
>   button displayed in that dialog. If you click it an information
>   message like this will be shown:
>
> > {APP_NAME} now works with the connections file used by MySQL Workbench
> >     if it is installed.
> >
> > {APP_NAME} will attempt to merge all existing connections with MySQL
> >     Workbench and in order to do this MySQL Workbench must not be running.
> >
> > Please make sure MySQL Workbench is closed to continue with the
> >     merging operation.  If you choose not to migrate connections now, you
> >     will be prompted later to perform the migration.
>
> Also note that in the latest versions of the 3 aforementioned products
>   the migration of connection information can be delayed to be done at a
>   later time or delayed indefinitely, which means the connection
>   information will remain in the product's configuration file until a
>   manual migration of this information is performed.